# Getting different results while Inserting some elements into a splay tree

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, insert, binary-search-tree

I have tried to insert some elements into a splay tree using java and checked the result through some online simulators. But  I am getting different results in different websites. I have tried to insert the following keys:

```
12 25 10 27
```

the results I have got are as follows:

result 1:

[image]

result 2:

[image]

My question is which one is correct?

Comment: Both of them are. It totally depends on implementation. Here's the implementation of author of splay tree, Daniel D. Sleator, http://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/ftp-site/splaying/SplayTree.java

Comment: but if i follow the rules from bottom up approach, i get the result 1 @halfo